# Cannot login oracle database using other users

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I'm currently using oracle xe c18.  I can login using `sqlplus / AS SYSDBA` as oracle user.  However, the command does not work for other users.  It always shows an error `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.  I already give SUID and GUID to all installation files.  What's the problem?

Comment: How did you create those "other users"? With Oracle, database users are not necessarily the same as OS users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you gave is using 'os authentication' to connect.  That is, the OS user issuing the command is a member of the os group "DBA".  (Or, on Windblows, "ORA_DBA").  I hope you did not change ownership or permission of any of the files.